# How to set LaTeX so that PDF reader opens PDF file in a prespecified view?

Tags: pdf, viewers

When I open PDF file generated from `.tex` files in Adobe Reader I obtain 200% view and I'd like it to have much smaller? Are there some settings for my `.tex` files allowing to do that?

Comment: Related Question: [Hyperref fill windows PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/hyperref-fill-windows-pdf).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This can be done with the help of the [`hyperref` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). See the [package documentation](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf#page=18&zoom=100,0,630) (bottom of p.18).

It gives you the settings
`pdfstartpage` and `pdfstartview` which can be used as package option or with `\hypersetup{...}` in the preamble.

`pdfstartpage` awaits the page number and `pdfstartview` one of the following values:

```
XYZ    left top zoom            Sets a coordinate and a zoom factor. If any
                                one is null, the source link value is used. null
                                null null will give the same values as the current page.
Fit                             Fits the page to the window.
FitH   top                      Fits the width of the page to the window.
FitV   left                     Fits the height of the page to the window.
FitR   left bottom right top    Fits the rectangle specified by the four coordinates to the window.
FitB                            Fits the page bounding box to the window.
FitBH  top                      Fits the width of the page bounding box to the window.
FitBV  left                     Fits the height of the page bounding box to the window.
```

For changing the zoom level you should use `XYZ` and then the zoom factor as the third value (100% = 1, 200% = 2, etc).
See the `hyperref` manual for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}
```

Comment: What is new here in comparison to the more detailed already accepted answer?

Comment: @dexteritas Sometimes, "less is more".