# Open PDF to a Prescribed Bookmark

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

### Background:

I have a *one* page document with header information at the top.
I would like the document to automatically scrolling past this header when it is opened.

The following theorem is only relevant in case you are wondering why I don't just generate two versions of the document.

---

### Theorem: I should *not* generate a version without this info (until release).

*Proof* : This information is extremely relevant to me. So I need to have that there. But, this is really not useful for anyone when they *start* to review a document. However, once the reviewer wants to provide me feedback, then that information becomes relevant as they need to tell me which version of which document they are commenting on.

Thus this information needs to always be there.  QED. :-)

---

### Question:

I am wondering if there is some kind of `\hyperset{}` call which will tell the PDF reader to open the document, at the `\phantomsection` labelled `start of doc` (in the MWE below).

In the references section below is a link to a similar titled question, but I don't see how to use that to open to a particular bookmark.
One solution would be to compute the coordinate and use `\hypersetup{XYZ=left top zoom}`, but wondering if there is an easier way.

The MWE below has a bookmark which if you click on will take you to the spot where I'd like the document to open to automatically.

### References:

- [How to set LaTeX so that PDF reader opens PDF file in a prespecified view?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-to-set-latex-so-that-pdf-reader-opens-pdf-file-in-a-prespecified-view)
- [Add PDF bookmark manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/add-pdf-bookmark-manually)

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.0in, paperheight=25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH}

\begin{document}
This part at the top of the file contain information related to
this file including:
\begin{itemize}
    \item file name,
    \item file version,
    \item edit history,
    \item list of things still to be completed, etc..
\end{itemize}
And this info can be quite long, in a few cases.
So the PDF should open with the following rule at the top.
\hrule\medskip

\phantomsection
\label{start of doc}
\pdfbookmark{Start of Doc}{start of doc}
\textbf{Begin of Actual Document:}

This is the start of the actual document, the info
above can be quite long, so I would prefer that the 
document open to this point in the page.

\bigskip
\textbf{Dummy text to fill page:}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FitH` has a parameter for the vertical position that can be calculated using `\hypercalcbp`. The example uses package `zref-savepos` for pdfTeX or XeTeX (that support `\pdfsavepos`) to get the vertical position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.0in, paperheight=25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH \hypercalcbp{\zposy{start}sp}}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}


\begin{document}
This part at the top of the file contain information related to
this file including:
\begin{itemize}
    \item file name,
    \item file version,
    \item edit history,
    \item list of things still to be completed, etc..
\end{itemize}
And this info can be quite long, in a few cases.
So the PDF should open with the following rule at the top.
\hrule\medskip

\phantomsection
\zsavepos{start}
\label{start of doc}
\pdfbookmark{Start of Doc}{start of doc}
\textbf{Begin of Actual Document:}

This is the start of the actual document, the info
above can be quite long, so I would prefer that the
document open to this point in the page.

\bigskip
\textbf{Dummy text to fill page:}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems as if this does not require the use of `\phantomsection`, `\label`, and `\pdfbookmark`. I had only put them there assuming they were going to be needed.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for editing. The bookmark still might be useful for PDF viewers that do not support `OpenAction`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, Can `\zsavepos` also save the page information?, such that one can also locate a specific page, (and the use it in combination with `hyperref`'s `pdfstartpage` options to start the viewer at the right page).

Comment: @alfC A page number can be extracted by package `refcount` and a `\label`. Or there is `zref-abspage`.