# How to set LaTeX so that PDF reader opens Beamer presentation without scrolling?

Tags: beamer, hyperref

This question is closely related to [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-to-set-latex-so-that-pdf-reader-opens-pdf-file-in-a-prespecified-view).

I am using the `beamer` package, which automatically loads the `hyperref` package, so the only thing to do is to pass additional options to `hyperref`:

`\hypersetup{...}`

I am using the option `pdfpagelayout=SinglePage`, but when I open the presentation file it appears **with the scrolling option enabled** , which is highly undesirable for presentations. How can I force the single page view on my presentation?

Comment: Did you try `\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}`? It works fine.

Comment: @Eddy_Em Yes I did, but I'd rather prefer a "windowed" solution.

Comment: Is is scrolling from page to page or is the aspect ratio of your window just such that it can't all fit on there? `pdfview=Fit` might be a good `\hypersetup` option to try.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Well, I tried the seemingly similar option `pdfstartview=Fit`, with no effect. Regarding the aspect ratio, the PDF viewer window (Adobe Reader X) opens maximized...by the way, `pdfview=Fit` is not working, either.

Comment: Does it do the expected thing with Acrobat?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue using `Evince` to show pdf files.

The following works for me:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
   pdfview=Fit,
   pdfstartview=Fit
}
```

I hope helps.