# how to increase the width of a page to fit the fullscreen mode of pdf

Tags: beamer, pdf, fullpage

I'm preparing a presentation in beamer. I've noticed some undesirable space if the fullscreen mode is enabled, see the below picture

[image]

As you can see, the red rectangles show the undesirable space. I would like the page to be stretched properly and automatically so that I can show the presentation in a fullscreen mode without scrolling down. This question is similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119500/how-to-set-latex-so-that-pdf-reader-opens-beamer-presentation-without-scrolling) however, the answer in the aforementioned link doesn't solve the problem. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{
   pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
   pdfview=Fit,
   pdfstartview=Fit
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\blindtext
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\blindtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting pdf tool in presentation mode? Or are you trying to change the format of the slides?

Comment: @Rico, what do you mean by "pdf tool in presentation mode"?

Comment: Things that come to mind as parts of a solution: if you have a widescreen display, you may want to add the `aspectratio=169` option to your beamer `\documentclass` command. Everything else is a function of your PDF viewer, as indicated in the linked questions.

Comment: That is not full screen mode, is it? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @cfr, what you see is 'Fit one full page to window' in pdf. Fullscreen mode is `Fit one full page to window` without showing the rest of details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this to enable full screen mode:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen}]{beamer}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\blindtext
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\blindtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If the screen on which you prepare the slides has a different shape than the screen you will show them on, then you will get space at the sides when you display them in preparation, but not when you show them. Typically, this will be the case because most computer screens are now wider relative to their height than is the case for LCD projection rectangles. These do not have a screen as such - you can project it onto a wall if you like - but they project an image of particular width and height. It is the ratio of these dimensions which you want your slides to match - not the ratio of the dimensions of the screen which happens to belong to the computer you produce them on.

Generally, Beamer's defaults work fine. Unless you know that the equipment you will be using is non-standard, it is reasonably safe to assume that its width/height ratio will match Beamer's defaults. (I've never used equipment for which this was not the case.)

## EDIT

If you are getting space at the sides when you try projecting your slides, then you are using equipment for which Beamer's default guess is wrong.

By default, Beamer assumes a 4:3 aspect ratio. If that is incorrect, you can change it using the `aspectratio` key:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=<aspect ratio>]{beamer}
```

Beamer knows about the following aspect ratios:

- `1610`: 16:10
- `169`: 16:9
- `149`: 14:9
- `141`: 1.41:1
- `54`: 5:4
- `43`: 4:3 [default]
- `32`: 3:2

See page 76 for further details.

Comment: I've tried fullscreen option but with no luck. The display in my university shows the black sides. I think beamerposter package is a solution for my problem. I will show answer using beamerposter package.

Comment: Then you need to figure out the correct ratio in order to give that information to Beamer. I would not recommend using **beamerposter** unless you are really displaying a poster. You just need to pass the right option to Beamer. It uses the most likely ratio by default, but it knows about others.

Comment: using `[aspectratio=169]` actually solved the problem but still **beamerposter** offers enough space for more info. But Fullscreen does nothing regarding this matter. If you can modify the answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated with information about the aspect ratio. If you are presenting a poster, by all means use `beamerposter`. But if you are using slides, then squeezing more information into the same space is not an advantage. It will just make things harder for your audience to read. The projection onto the screen is a fixed size. If you put more into it, it has to be smaller. **beamerposter** is not designed for this usage - any more than Beamer is designed for posters. It is not just a question of getting an appropriate ratio to fill the space. Scale matters here.

Comment: `FullScreen` opens the slides in presentation mode i.e. no menu bar or window frame visible: your content consumes the entire screen. It does not affect the size of the slides or the aspect ratio. It just affects the default view mode for the slides when initially opened. (Most viewers will ask before allowing it to open in this mode. At least Okular and acroread both do this when I set `FullScreen`.)