# Error after converting to PDF: "Unknown destination type: 'null'."

Tags: pdftex, pdf, tex-core, texshop, acrobat

We have a report written in a LaTeX editor and then converted to PDF using pdflatex. When this PDF is opened in Preview it is fine, however when it is opened in Adobe Acrobat (both Reader and Pro) there is an error upon opening the document that says:

"Unknown destination type 'null'."

[image: Acrobat Reader error message: "Unknown destination type 'null'."]

I haven't been able to find any other questions/topics about this on any forums so I am coming to the TeX experts to see if anyone can point me in the right direction. I am not a regular user of TeX / LaTeX and am just helping to troubleshoot the issue. I am thinking that the unknown destination refers to a link or reference that is incomplete, but that's just a guess. Any advice, information, or guidance is much appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot answer, but I do know that the Adobe products will detect and reject some PDF errors that other readers ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to resolve the error.

Using TeXShop to edit the .tex file, I saw a line that included:

```
pdfstartview={null null null}
```

I first commented the line out using a `%` symbol, re-created a PDF, and the error no longer popped up when opening the PDF in Acrobat.

I then went back to the .tex file in TeXShop, removed the `%` so that the line was being read again, but changed `{null null null}` to `{XYZ null null 1.00}`. Again, created a PDF, and the error didn't pop up when opening in Acrobat.

I don't know enough about TeX to know exactly why this happened and this fix worked, but posting here for others to find if they encounter the same error.

EDIT: As noted in one of the comments/replies, this looks like an error due to the `pdfstartview={}` setting being incomplete in our initial report. Where we had:

```
pdfstartview={null null null}
```

The correct syntax requires an `XYZ` string at beginning of the `{in brackets}` inputs.

Comment: Maybe a the answer in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-to-set-latex-so-that-pdf-reader-opens-pdf-file-in-a-prespecified-view gives some insight (also in relation to the hyperref package) and also  https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html.

Comment: Thanks @albert, this is very helpful. I think simply having pdfstartview={null null null} was causing the error as it's an incomplete setting without the XYZ.