# How to fix the font size of pdf after running in winEdt?

Tags: viewers, adobe

I am writing a dissertation (Thesis) using WinEdt editor. After saving and clicking on Pdf Texify, the pdf file always open at 46.9% zoom. How can I permanently fix the pdf size to open at 100% zoom? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WinEdt, but with  your pdf viewer. Which one go you use?

Comment: I am using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

Comment: If you're using `hyperref`, you can add `\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}` to your preamble. It tells pdf viewers to open the document with a zoom of 1.00, with default X and Y position. See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16473/74459).

Comment: You'd better use `SumatraPDF` which is free, ultra-fast and doesn't lock  .pdf files. In addition it understands the synchronisation files, so that it  has direct and inverse search capabilities.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments